# When is it appropriate to buy Black Cleaver on ADCs?

Tags: league-of-legends

What are the ADCs/Marksmen that benefit from buying Black Cleaver over another item, like Last Whisper, and what are the reasons for that?

I have tried it with Ashe, and it worked pretty well with her Q, but are there any other adcs that do well as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most notable ADCs that synergise well, especially after the rework, are Lucian, Miss Fortune, Ashe (post-rework on Q) and Kalista.

The reason why ADCs ever buy Black Cleaver over LW is either because they are able to stack it consistently, or they have a great use for the Phage passive. In this retrospect, those 4 ADCs mentioned above would have more use for Black Cleaver than LW or other armor penetration items.